# How to send input data from an html form to an external API?

Tags: html, api, http-post, http-get

I am trying to create a currency converter web app which uses currency API but I cannot find how to pass the data from the forms to the API and based on that data the API to return the requested currency conversion.

I tried to pass the data from the forms to the api from, to and amount values like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
                <h2>Currency Calculator</h2>
                <p class="lead">Convert the currency</p>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" min="1" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                        <select class="form-control" id="currency-1" required>
                            <option>BGN</option>
                            <option>EUR</option>
                            <option>USD</option>
                            <option>GBP</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                        <label>convert to</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="currency-2" required>
                            <option>EUR</option>
                            <option>USD</option>
                            <option>BGN</option>
                            <option>GBP</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <a target="_blank" button class="btn calculate-btn btn-primary mb-2"
                       href=https://apilayer.net/api/convert?access_key=f369836ea64d991b6264fe9b6e19262a&from=#currency-1&to=#currency-2&amount=#amount&format=1>Show
                        me the result!</a>
```

What I expected was to pass the data from the html forms to the api but, api returned the following error:

> {"success":false,"error":{"code":401,"info":"You have entered an
>   invalid \"from\" property. [Example: from=EUR]"}}

Answer (score 0):

I also did the following:

```
<script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {

                            var base_url = "https://apilayer.net/api/convert?access_key=f36e636ea64d851b6264fe9b6e19262a/convert?";

                            var source1 = $("#currency-1").attr("value");
                            var source2 = $("#currency-2").attr("value");
                            var amount = $("#amount").attr("value");

                            var whole_query = base_url + '&from=' + source1 + '&to=' + source2 + '&amount=' + amount;
                            $(".query_exec").attr("href", whole_query);


                            $('#source1').keyup(function () {
                                $('#currency-1').html($(this).val());
                                source1 = $(this).val();

                                whole_query = base_url + '&from=' + source1 + '&to=' + source2 + '&amount=' + amount;
                                $(".query_exec").attr("href", whole_query);

                            });

                            $('#source2').keyup(function () {
                                $('#currency-2').html($(this).val());
                                source2 = $(this).val();

                                whole_query = base_url + '&from=' + source1 + '&to=' + source2 + '&amount=' + amount;
                                $(".query_exec").attr("href", whole_query);

                            });

                            $('#amount').keyup(function () {
                                $('#amount').html($(this).val());
                                amount = $(this).val();

                                whole_query = base_url + '&from=' + source1 + '&to=' + source2 + '&amount=' + amount;
                                $(".query_exec").attr("href", whole_query);


                        });
                    });
                </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the api key to the end point of the service returning the exchange price.

Here is the sample application web api on nodejs and client build on angularjs

Client : https://github.com/krishna28/exchange-client

Server api: https://github.com/krishna28/exchangeapi